# Customizing tint color of UIBarButtonSystemItem with UIAppearance API

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I know I can customize the `UIBarButtonItem` text via

```
setTitleTextAttributes:forState:
```

There is also a way to customize `UITabBar` icons via

```
setSelectedImageTintColor:
```

Is there a way to customize the tint color of a `UIBarButtonSystemItem`, (e.g. the trash icon color), just to have a consistent UX? I could not find anything.

If this is not possible, how would I proceed? Should I save a color modified version of the icon? Where can I find it? What would be the easiest way to modify it?

**EDIT**

To clarify, it's not the background color of the `UIBarButtonItem` I am asking for, but the color of the contour of the icon.

**EDIT**

Setting the tint color of the `UIBarButtonItem` yields the background color of the button set.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    UIBarButtonItem* trashButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target:nil action:nil];

    trashButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    UIViewController* viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [viewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:trashButton];

    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    return YES;
}
```

yields [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yis6z5j3wzamdmm/Untitled.png).

**EDIT 2**

It turns out that the contour color of the system icons in fact can be set via `tintColor` property of `UIBarButtonItem`, however only if its `style` property has the value `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain`. (Even then, some colors are special and leave the contour white. One such color is `[UIColor blackColor]`) However, using the `UIBarButtonItem` in a `UINavigationBar` the `style` is forced to be `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered`. In this case, `tintColor` sets the background color of the button and leaves the contour white.

As I am using the `UIBarButtonItem`s in a navigation bar, my problem still remains unsolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved my problem by changing the color of the bar button system item png file in an external editor, including that image to the project and loading it via

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UIButtonBarTrashBlack"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(myAction)];
```

I have found the internal system image using the helpful [UIKit-Artwork-Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor).

I have edited the color of the artwork using the free software [GIMP](http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Download.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpful answer! This indeed seems the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Too bad that you can't set the width of the UIBarButtonItem in a UINavigationBar :( Now the button doesn't look anything like the System item.

Answer (score 10):

**Note**: The following only works for buttons added to a toolbar, not a navbar.

Use the `tintColor` property of `UIBarButtonItem`. Either call it on a specific instance or call it on the `appearance` for all button items.

Be careful setting the tint for all button items via `appearance`. Not all button items look right when you set the tint.

Update:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnAdd = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addAction)];
btnAdd.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

This will make the button's icon black (the background will be whatever the toolbar's tint is).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. As I suspected, this changes the background color of the barButton. Say, my navbar is green and the button backgrounds are green, too, and I want to display black text and the `UIBarButtonSystemItem`s also black on a green background, how would I achieve that? My only problem is the black color of the `UIBarButtonSystemItem`, which by default is white and I can't modify it.

Comment: I do this in my app. For one of the system type bar button items, I set the button's tintColor. This changes the color of the icon only. I do this for bar button items I add to a toolbar.

Comment: Just tried it and retried it and retried it. Using iOS 6.1 SDK. Setting the tint color to black I am getting a white trash can on black background. I need a black can on a green background.

Comment: I just verified that the code I posted is correct for changing the icon's color, not the button's background. Make sure you comment out all other `UIBarButtonItem appearance` code and try just the `tintColor` on a single button.

Comment: I've updated my question with the sample app to verify. Is this code supposed to do what you say?

Comment: OK, I see the issue. I've stated that my solution is for toolbars. Your updated code shows you are putting the bar button item in a navbar. I need to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Oh... Toolbar != Navbar. I didn't specify. This is my fault. Weird if this makes a difference.

Comment: Just tested for Toolbars. Same issue. Difference is: On toolbar I can choose `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` which is the default. On navbar `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered` is forced. But even for plain style, the trash can contours stay white with tint color set to black.

Comment: Huh? You don't set a style for the system icons. See the code I posted. Now add that button item as follows: `self.toolbarItems = @[ btnAdd ];`.

Comment: What's the difference to the line `trashButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];`? Isn't that the equivalent of your code?

Comment: +1 for staying with me. See my new edit, if you are still a bit interested. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me on the Navbar for UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using black color, use this:

> [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]; // [UIColor
>   blackColor] makes it white

Comment: Got a down with no comment? Very useful